# Show Android notifications until I explicitly close them

Tags: notifications

My smartphone is nice and reminds me of approaching appointments (Etar) or other stuff.

But sometimes I just do not look at the notifications and when I switch off the phone, the next time they are gone.

Is there any way to *keep notifications showing until I explicitly close them*?

Comment: I don't think so; except for missed calls, I've never seen a notification surviving a boot. All there is to my knowledge is a hidden feature to call "notification history" (which you'd need to do explicitly). Don't think that would solve your issue, though, as then you'd need to remember calling that each time you switch the device on.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to develop such a thing?

Comment: No idea. This site is for end users, not for developers. As there's such a thing as "notification history", the information must be stored somewhere. But whether that contains if and when a notification was closed by the user is beyond my knowledge.